# What to do with missing values if missing has clear meaning?

Tags: missing-data

I am trying to model the daily demand of a retailer's products, based on the prices of competitors offering the same products (among other variables). I have 20 columns with the prices of various competitors for this specific product on the same date. The retailer however has over 80 000 products in its product range during the observed period and of course not all competitors offer all those products as well. In fact, in most of the cases, only 2 or 3 competitors offer the same product. This leads to a lot of missing values, indicating that this competitor does not offer this product at that moment.

I do not want to simply impute these missing values, given the large proportion of missing values, as well as the fact that they contain valuable information on their own: does a competitor provide this product or not.

Is there a supervised learning algorithm that handles missing values as specific cases?

Comment: This question appears to be more appropriate for https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You are right, imputing does not make too much sense here. You can make supervised learning algorithms kind of handle this missing values as specific cases. Just add one additional variable for each competitor. (binary yes/no flag indicating if competitor offers the product). In this way ML algorithms like Random Forest can somehow use this information. This is one often used way on how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that imputation is not a good idea in this situation as the information of missingness gets lost. However, given the idea of creating additional features which indicate if a value is known or missing, you could try to fill missing values by the mean and than use LogisticRegression on your data.